# Is it safe to display HTML code decoded by decodeURIComponent from a URL?

Tags: javascript, html, security, xss, openlayers

## General

I am not sure whether it is safe to display some text entered by an user in this way:

An argument from a URL is decoded by `decodeURIComponent()`. Afterwards, line breaks are replaced using `text.replace(/\n/g, '<br/>')`.
The resulting string is displayed in an OpenLayers marker.

In this way, HTML from the user is embedded in the webpage.

## Concrete example

http://map.openseamap.org allows for the creation of permalinks (Top menu > Tools > Permalinks)
The site decodes the URL as shown above and displays a marker on the page.

Example:
http://map.openseamap.org/map/?zoom=15&mlat=53.62053&mlon=11.46929&mtext=%3Cscript%3E%0A%20alert(%27Hello%20World!%27)%3B%0A%3C%2Fscript%3E&layers=BTFFFFFFFFF0FFFFFFFF

Contains:

```
<script>
    alert('Hello World!');
</script>
```

The code is embedded in the page, but is not executed.

Can this way to display the text be exploited?

You can find the code of the site here:
http://github.com/OpenSeaMap/online_chart

The code for decoding is in index.php on line 138:
http://github.com/OpenSeaMap/online_chart/blob/master/index.php#L137

If you have a better solution, a pull request is welcome!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is it safe?

## **No.**

#### Example:

I used a payload of `<IMG SRC=/ onerror="alert(document.domain)"></img>`

Here's the permalink (note that this will cause several alerts to appear on the page, nothing malicious, but a little annoying): http://map.openseamap.org/map/?zoom=17&mlat=53.62429&mlon=11.47198&mtext=%3CIMG%20SRC%3D%2F%20onerror%3D%22alert(document.domain)%22%3E%3C%2Fimg%3E&layers=BTFFFFFFFFF0FFFFFFFF

Your implementation is actually a little extra dangerous since it obfuscates the payload enough for built-in browser tools like Chrome's XSS auditor to not detect it. Not that leaving this to the browser is acceptable, but this makes for a very universal XSS vulnerability.

You still need to escape 'dangerous' characters like `<`, `>`, `'`, `"`, and `&`. In my opinion, HTML from this parameter should not render at all, as the intention appears to be a plaintext comment. The context we need to escape for here appears to be pretty much a standard HTML context, so the aforementioned characters should be sufficient to prevent injection (at least in that spot, I didn't check everywhere!). That means `<` becomes `&lt;`, `>` becomes `&gt;`, `'` becomes `&#039;`, `"` becomes `&quot;`, and `&` becomes `&amp;`.

I'm not saying you should do the conversion from scratch, just giving a rough idea of what needs to happen. Here's a great resource that every web developer should read at least a few times: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! I use the he library now (https://github.com/mathiasbynens/he).

Comment: @aAXEe Cool - I have no experience with that particular library, but it sounds like you are definitely on the right track. If you felt like this answer helped to solve your problem, please mark it as accepted. Good luck!

Comment: > becomes &gt;, not &rt;. Apparently, can't edit this, because edit have to be at least 6 characters long.